# Filtering on RadGrid not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I created a RadGrid with a couple of fields for filtering and I can't seem to get the filtering to work. I can see it clearly posting back (the ajax spinny circle thing) after typing something in the filter box, however my results are always the same. I am using the following definition in the aspx file:

```
<telerik:RadGrid PageSize="4" ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadGrid1_SelectedIndexChanged" Skin="Black" ShowFooter="True"
                    ShowStatusBar="True" AllowFilteringByColumn="True"
                    EnableLinqExpressions="False">
                    <MasterTableView AllowFilteringByColumn="true" Caption="Select a Customer">
                        <Columns>
                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn CurrentFilterFunction="StartsWith" HeaderText="First Name" AllowFiltering="true" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#GetFirstName(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem"))%>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Last Name" AllowFiltering="true" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#GetLastName(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem"))%>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Address">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#GetAddress(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem"))%>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Shop">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#GetShopName(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem"))%>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        </Columns>
                        <RowIndicatorColumn>
                            <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
                        </RowIndicatorColumn>
                        <ExpandCollapseColumn>
                            <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
                        </ExpandCollapseColumn>
                    </MasterTableView>
                    <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true" EnablePostBackOnRowClick="True">
                        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
                    </ClientSettings>
                    <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages" />
                </telerik:RadGrid>
```

And I got the following in my code behind:

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    BusinessLayer.Customers Customers = new BusinessLayer.Customers();

    Customers.GetBySQLStatement(GetCustomerSQL());

    this.RadGrid1.DataSource = Customers;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Any other results of this one?  I see a similar issue, but have all GridBoundColumns with the DataField defined.  Iny my NeedDataSource event handler, the CurrentFilterFunction and CurrentFilterValues are set correctly for the column(s) filtered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add **DataField** for each column or use **GridBoundColumns** rather than GridTemplateColumns.

Comment: after searching several posts, the DataField suggestion has worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Your grid definition looks OK to me - not sure where the issue is. I use the Telerik grid from some time now and what I would do if in your shoes would be to debug my code, see what the MasterTableView.FilterExpression value is inside NeedDataSource and whether the returned records are filtered with that expression and passed to the grid.

Dick

Comment: Thanks! voted this answer up.. might not be direct answer to the question but certainly helpful for debugging radgrid filtering issues and helped me.

Comment: OnNeedDataSource is not firing when I do a filter.  Only when the page first loads.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub RadGrid_NeedDataSource(ByVal source As RadGrid, ByVal e As GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs) 'Handles RadGrid.NeedDataSource
    Dim RadGrid As RadGrid = CType(source, RadGrid)
    'Dim nestedItem As GridNestedViewItem = CType(source.NamingContainer, GridNestedViewItem)
    'Dim CustomerID = CType(nestedItem.ParentItem, GridDataItem).GetDataKeyValue(source.Attributes("TableID"))

    Dim gridSortString As String = RadGrid.MasterTableView.SortExpressions.GetSortString()

    Dim args As New DataSourceSelectArguments(gridSortString)

    If gridSortString Is Nothing Then
        RadGrid.DataSource = GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM [" + source.Attributes("TableName") + "] ") 'Where CustomerID = N'" + CustomerID + "'
    Else
        RadGrid.DataSource = GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM [" + source.Attributes("TableName") + "] ORDER BY " & gridSortString) 'Where CustomerID = N'" + CustomerID + "'
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and describe your code. Code only answers are not the best option.